# Different grounds

Tags: symbol

What is the meaning of different type of grounds in electronic circuits? Can we use any ground in any circuit or not?

[image]

Comment: highly similar:  http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/237439/where-do-these-grounding-wires-go , http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/162591/how-to-add-ground-to-dc-circuit

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/5EBO6.png from another ans at stack site

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They represent different ground types.

The first is "circuit ground" and is a reference point in the circuit against which all voltages are measured.

The second is chassis ground and represents a connection to the metal enclosure the circuit is in.

The third represents earth ground and is a physical connection to the ground under your feet.

3 is often used in place of 1 though.

Also you sometimes get various different combinations of the three representing different ground zones in a circuit (digital ground, analog ground, power ground, etc) at the designer's discretion.

Comment: I agree with you, but are these differences standardized or it's just a sort of a convention?

Comment: They are as standard as resistors. I.e., some people use /\/\/ and some use |====| ;) It's standard, but not everyone sticks to the standard.

Comment: Personally I use the triangular thing for resistances and the box style for generic impedances, possibly purely resistive

Comment: Officially /\/\/ is an American resistor, and |====| is a European resistor.  I'm British (alas) and I was brought up on /\/\/ for resistors, and still use them to this day.

Comment: Yeah I know that, but I think the box style is also official for impedances, so that's it. Here in Pisa (Italy) we use (they teach) the American style resistor anyway.